# Why are FM radio waves less susuceptible to interference than AM?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

When studying modulation of radio waves (or of most electromagnetic waves for that matter) I came across that question. Why are FM waves less susceptible to interference than AM waves? I know that in FM waves the frequency has been modulated to carry the signal by superimposing the signal wave to the carrier wave and for AM the amplitude has been varied by a similar process however what I don't understand is why FM radio waves are less susceptible to interference. Is it because when two waves interfere it is easier to change the amplitude as compared to the frequency, if so why? I can't think of any proper explanations so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This question has been marked as a duplicate however I don't understand the solutions from the other question. Also I fear that asking for clarification on that question will not gain the attention necessary as it is from 2 years ago.

Comment: This might be better suited for http://ham.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94198/